# How to display results in a dedicated buffer?

Tags: elisp

If my current buffer is `foo`, and I run `C-x C-b` (aka `list-buffers`), my Emacs window splits in two, with `foo` occupying one of the two resulting windows, and a dedicated `*Buffer List*` buffer occupying the other one.  At the end of this operation, `foo` remains the active buffer, and `point` remains were it was before `C-x C-b` was executed.

I want to write an interactive function that displays a multi-page output in a similar way: split window if necessary, bring up a dedicated buffer, leave the active buffer as it was before the function was run.

The best I've managed to do is a function with the following structure:

```
(defun my-func ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((this-buffer (current-buffer))
        (other-buffer (get-buffer-create "*my-func's Dedicated Buffer*")))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window other-buffer)
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert (compute-pages-and-pages-of-stuff))
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window this-buffer)))
```

This works, more or less, but I thought that Emacs already had built-in syntax to streamline such code.

IOW, I thought there was a special form analogous to the (fictional) `WITH-BUFFER-OTHER-WINDOW` in the snippet below:

```
(defun my-func ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((other-buffer (get-buffer-create "*my-func's Dedicated Buffer*")))
        (WITH-BUFFER-OTHER-WINDOW other-buffer
           (erase-buffer)
           (insert (compute-pages-and-pages-of-stuff))
           (beginning-of-buffer))))
```

or maybe even

```
(defun my-func ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((other-buffer (get-buffer-create "*my-func's Dedicated Buffer*")))
        (WITH-BUFFER-OTHER-WINDOW other-buffer
            (compute-pages-and-pages-of-stuff))))
```

I've tried forms like `save-excursion` and `save-current-buffer`, but they don't reproduce the desired behavior.

Is there a built-in way to carry out the operation described above?

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest you can get by leveraging the built-ins `display-buffer` and `with-current-buffer`:

```
(defun my-func ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (get-buffer-create "*my-func's Dedicated Buffer*")))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert (compute-pages-and-pages-of-stuff))
      (goto-char (point-min)))
    (display-buffer buffer)))
```

If you use this pattern so much that it starts annoying you, feel free to define a helper macro:

```
(defmacro my-setup-and-display-buffer (name &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1))
  (let ((buffer (make-symbol "buffer")))
    `(let ((,buffer (get-buffer-create ,name)))
       (with-current-buffer ,buffer
         ,@body)
       (display-buffer ,buffer))))

(my-setup-and-display-buffer "*my-func's Dedicated Buffer*"
  (erase-buffer)
  (insert (compute-pages-and-pages-of-stuff))
  (goto-char (point-min)))
```